# Discrete Mathematics - Proof by Cases or Proof by elimination of cases

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We have to prove the following questions using division algorithm and Proof by Cases or Proof by the elimination of cases :

1. The square of any odd integer is of the form 8n+1.

Attempt: By division algorithm, if we divide an odd integer by 8, the form can be 8n+k where k=1,3,5,7. Square of an odd integer is also odd. Now how do I eliminate the cases where k=3,5,7?

2.The cube of any integer is of the form 9n,9n+1 or 9n+8.

Attempt: Again by division algorithm, the form can be 9n+k, where k is an integer and k<9. Again how do I eliminate cases where k is not equal to 0,1 or 8 ?

Please help!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the square of $8n+3$?

Comment: Yeah I solved the first question by checking for 5 and 7. But I was thinking if you assume the square odd which is also odd as 8n+k where k=1,3,5,7, the how will you back solve? Thanks.

Comment: (Sorry I think you already got it, so perhaps this was not necessary.) Let me give you another hint. $(8n+3)(8n+3) = 64n^2 + 48n + 9$ What do you get when you divide $64n^2 + 48n + 9$ by 8? Now do it for the general case $8n+k$ and perhaps $pn+k$ for any $p$, not just $8$.

Comment: I already did. Thanks for the reply. Why I was stuck was because I assumed square themselves to be of form 8n+k.  But is this really a dead end?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Any integer can be expressed as $8n+k$ where $k \leq 0 \leq 7$.

Comment: What I mean is that if I assume "square of odd integers" of the form 8n+k, where k<8, integer, then how will I proceed. I certainly cannot square root them and see if they result in an integer?

Comment: Ok I get it. sqrt(8k+1) = sqrt((4m+1)^2) but rest can not be represented. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the various cases:
\begin{align}
n&=8k+1 & n^2&=8k^2+16k+1=8(k^2+2k)+1 \\
n&=8k+3 & n^2&=8k^2+48k+9=8(k^2+6k+1)+1 \\
n&=8k+5 & n^2&=8k^2+80k+25=8(k^2+10k+3)+1 \\
n&=8k+7 & n^2&=8k^2+112k+49=8(k^2+14k+6)+1
\end{align}
You don't have to eliminate cases.

More easily, with congruences
\begin{align}
n&\equiv 1\pmod{8} & n^2&\equiv1\pmod{8}\\
n&\equiv 3\pmod{8} & n^2&\equiv9\equiv1\pmod{8}\\
n&\equiv 5\pmod{8} & n^2&\equiv25\equiv1\pmod{8}\\
n&\equiv 7\pmod{8} & n^2&\equiv49\equiv1\pmod{8}
\end{align}

For the cubes, you have
\begin{align}
n&=3k & n^3&=9\cdot3k^3\\
n&=3k+1 & n^3&=27k^3+27k^2+9k+1=\dots\\
n&=3k+2 & n^3&=\dots
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For the square of any odd integers I would write them in the forms $4n+1$ and $4n-1$. By multiplying them out you get
$$(4n+1)^2 = 8(2n^2 + n) + 1$$
and
$$(4n-1)^2 = 8(2n^2 - n) + 1$$
which are both of the required form.

Try similar for the cube question.

Comment: Thanks BDN. I see that assuming directly the square of odd integer of the form 8n+k is a dead end. Now let me try question 2.

Comment: Your proof is redundant: numbers of the form $4n+1$ are exactly those of the form $4n-3$.

Comment: Any integer can be written as 3n,3n+1 and 3n+2. Now cubing all those will get the above forms. Now the last question: Why do we call this method elimination of cases? Or is it proof by cases how? @Ethan Bolker, Good catch. Take only 4n+1,4n+2 and 4n+3

Comment: You don't need $4n+2$ since it's even ... I've no opinion on which way you _name_ this argument.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @EthanBolker good point, I'll edit it.

Comment: @BDN. Only 4n+1 and 4n+3 will suffice.